# SelectItem + SetMultiple(true)+retrieving issue

Tags: java, smartgwt

I'm using the **`selectItem`** component with configuration:

```
SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
selectItem.setMultiple(true);
selectItem.setMultipleValueSeperator(",");
```

I am saving the selected values ( values from lookup ) to the Database, but while retrieving the these values ( select record, click edit ) on clicking edit button, getting the values as numbers seperated by comma. Please help to display multiple values as checked Items while retrieving from the Database.

Unable to show the values as checkboxes snapshot is as follows:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: can someone assist me on this please?

Comment: Can you show your code to set values to the `selectItem` after retrieving values? Better if you can post a standalone code to reproduce the case.